# SQL summing vs running totals

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm currently in disagreement with my colleague regarding the best design of our database.

We have a need to frequently access the total user balance from our database of transactions, we will potentially need to access this information several times a second.

He says that sql is fast and all we need to do is `SUM()` the transactions. I, on the other hand, believe that eventually with enough users and a large database our server will be spending most of its time summing the same records in the database. My solution is to have a separate table to keep a record of the totals.

Which one of us is right?

Comment: It takes time to write the data that calculates the totals.  Plus, if they quickly become incorrect, what's the point?

Comment: How large is the set of tables you're trying to query?

Comment: Is this OLTP or OLAP?

Comment: What about setting up a reporting master-slave relationship?

Comment: What's the expected number of transactions per user? In other words, how many rows (on average) need to be processed to produce one SUM? Also, how frequently are new transactions inserted per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an example for database denormalization. It makes the code more complex and introduces potential for inconsistencies, but the query will be faster. If that's worth it depends on the need for the performance boost.

The sum could also be quite fast (i.e. fast *enough*) if it can be indexed properly.

A third way would be using cached aggregates that are periodically recalculated. Works best if you don't need real-time data (such as for account activity up until yesterday, which you can maybe augment with real-time data from the smaller set of today's data).

Again, the tradeoff is between making things fast and keeping things simple (don't forget that complexity also tend to introduce bugs and increase maintenance costs). It's not a matter of one approach being "right" for all situations.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is a good one. My colleague and I are going to be arguing about the trade-offs. It all depends on how successful our site is. If we are successful our database will grow indefinitely and we'll be summing the entire thing many times a second.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that one solution fits all.

You can go very far with a good set of indexes and well written queries.  I would start with querying real time until you can't, and then jump to the next solution.

From there, you can go to storing aggregates for all non changing data (for example, beginning of time up to prior month), and just query the sum for any data that changes in this month.

You can save aggregated tables, but how many different kinds of aggregates are you going to save?  At some point you have to look into some kind of a multi dimensional structure.

Comment: It was our original plan to start with real time querying and then jump to the next solution. However, the more we develop the system the more impractical moving to another solution becomes.